# xQuery: Associating 2 attributes and returning data related to said attribute

Tags: attributes, xquery

I have an XML file that contains information about gym instructors (monitors) and the activity they teach (actividades). I am stuck trying to create a query which associates the monitor code attribute from the activities element with the details of each monitor in the monitores element.

The exact task in question is: "Return the details of each monitor that teaches an activity with 2 or more other monitors."

In the activities element there are two elements that have 2 monitors. I can get these using the following code:

```
for $test in doc("polideportivo.xml")/polideportivo/actividades/actividad/monitores 
where count($test/monitor) > 1 
return data($test/monitor/@codigo)
```

which gives me results of the code attributes that appear more than once in each activity:

```
<results>m002 m003 m004 m005</results>
```

But my problem lies when linking these codes to the codes of the monitors in the monitores element.

I thought at first of applying the above code to a variable using let but it shows every activity attribute instead of only those that have 2 or more.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Below I will leave a snippet of the XML:

```
<polideportivo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="polideportivo.xsd">
<monitores>
  <monitor codigo="m001">
    <nombre>Mario</nombre>
    <apellidos>Cansado Pérez</apellidos>
    <telefono>968222222</telefono>
    <salario>1200</salario>
  </monitor>
  <monitor codigo="m002">...</monitor>
  <monitor codigo="m003">...</monitor>
  <monitor codigo="m004">...</monitor>
  <monitor codigo="m005">...</monitor>
</monitores>
<actividades>
  <actividad codigo="a10">
   <nombre>Pilates</nombre>
   <duracion>55</duracion>
   <intensidad>Ligero</intensidad>
   <lugar>Sala Fitness</lugar>
   <horario>...</horario>
   <monitores>
    <monitor codigo="m001"/>
   </monitores>
</actividad>
<actividad codigo="a20">
   <nombre>Crosstraining</nombre>
   <duracion>55</duracion>
   <intensidad>Fuerte</intensidad>
   <lugar>Sala Fitness</lugar>
   <horario>
    <sesion>
     <día>Martes</día>
     <horas>
      <hora>10:00</hora>
      <hora>16:00</hora>
      <hora>20:00</hora>
    </horas>
   </sesion>
  </horario>
   <monitores>
    <monitor codigo="m002"/>
    <monitor codigo="m003"/>
   </monitores>
</actividad>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like

```
/*/monitores/monitor[
   some $actividad in /*/actividades/actividad 
   satisfies 
     ($actividad/monitores/monitor/@codigo = @codigo 
      and $actividad/monitores/monitor[2])]
```

is an XPath 2 and later (and that way also an XQuery 1 and later) expression that expresses your verbal description (I am not sure whether you want to check for two or more or at least two monitores, the sample checks for at least two.